# How to use select() correctly inside a loop?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking, gnu

I am trying to modify an example I found.

The example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define STDIN 0  // file descriptor for standard input

int main(void)
{
   struct timeval tv;
   fd_set readfds;

   tv.tv_sec = 2;
   tv.tv_usec = 500000;

   FD_ZERO(&readfds);
   FD_SET(STDIN, &readfds);

   // don't care about writefds and exceptfds:
   select(STDIN+1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);

   if (FD_ISSET(STDIN, &readfds))
       printf("A key was pressed!\n");
   else
       printf("Timed out.\n");

   return 0;
}
```

Which print time out if 2.5 seconds has passed without sending a message, otherwise printing a key was pressed.

I tried to put it inside a while loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define STDIN 0  // file descriptor for standard input

int main(void)
{
   fd_set readfds, temp;
   struct timeval tv;

   FD_ZERO(&readfds);
   FD_ZERO(&temp);
   FD_SET(STDIN, &readfds);

   while(1){
       
   temp = readfds;     
   tv.tv_sec = 2;
   tv.tv_usec = 500000;
   // don't care about writefds and exceptfds:
   if (select(STDIN+1, &temp, NULL, NULL, &tv) == -1)
       printf("err");

   if (FD_ISSET(STDIN, &temp))
   {
       printf("A key was pressed!\n");
   }
   else
       printf("Timed out.\n");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

In this code when I enter a key it keeps printing a key was pressed forever.

I read online the I have to set tv variable every time but still no help.

Do i need a temp  `fd_set`
? what am I wrong ?

Comment: The lack of correct indentation of your code might have tripped oyu up. Please fix it.

Comment: Lookup the returnvalue you get from `select()` and what it implies on the contents of `temp`. Also: a `-1` return is **not** an error.

Comment: You're never **reading** from the fd, so **of course** it is readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

                // Note: STDIN_FILENO, or fileno(stdin)
#define STDIN 0  // file descriptor for standard input

int main(void)
{
   fd_set readfds, temp;
   struct timeval tv;
   int ret,ch;

   FD_ZERO(&readfds);
   FD_ZERO(&temp);
   FD_SET(STDIN, &readfds);

   while(1){

        temp = readfds;
        tv.tv_sec = 2;
        tv.tv_usec = 500000;
        // don't care about writefds and exceptfds:
        ret = select(STDIN+1, &temp, NULL, NULL, &tv) ;
        if (ret == -1) {
                if (errno == EAGAIN) continue; // These are NOT Errors, but natural occuring events
                if (errno == EINTR) continue; // The are reported to avoid your select() to block for too long
                        perror("erreur");
                break;
                }
        else if (ret ==0) {
           printf("Timed out.\n");
                continue;
                }
                // Ok: select has returned > 0; there must be something to read
        if (FD_ISSET(STDIN, &temp)) {
                ch = getc(stdin); // Lookout: stdin is line-buffered
                printf("A key was pressed: %d!\n", ch);
                }
        }
   return 0;
}
```